# Can't get right the concatenate layer dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using this unet:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Conv2D, Activation,\
    MaxPooling2D, Conv2DTranspose, Dropout, Input, Concatenate, \
    LeakyReLU, Flatten, Reshape, Lambda, MaxPool2D

def conv2d_block(input, num_filters):
    x = Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)  
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    x = Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)  
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    return x

n_filters = 16

def build_unet(input_shape):
        inputs = Input(input_shape)
        
        c1 = conv2d_block(inputs, num_filters=n_filters * 1)
        p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)

        c2 = conv2d_block(p1, num_filters=n_filters * 2)
        p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)

        c3 = conv2d_block(p2,num_filters=n_filters * 4)
        p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)

        c4 = conv2d_block(p3, num_filters=n_filters * 8)
        p4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c4)

        c5 = conv2d_block(p4, num_filters=n_filters * 16)
        p5 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c5)
        p5 = Dropout(0.2)(p5)
        
        c6 = conv2d_block(p5, num_filters=n_filters * 32)
        c6 = Dropout(0.2)(c6)
    
        u6 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 16, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2),
                             padding='same')(c6)
        u6 = Concatenate()([u6, c6])
        c7 = conv2d_block(u6, num_filters=n_filters * 16)

        
        u7 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 8, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2),
                              padding='same')(c7)
        u7 = Concatenate()([u7, c7])
        c8 = conv2d_block(u7, num_filters=n_filters * 8)

        
        u8 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 4, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), 
                              padding='same')(c8)
        u8 = Concatenate()([u8, c8])
        c9 = conv2d_block(u8, num_filters=n_filters * 4)

         
        u9 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 2, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), 
                              padding='same')(c9)
        u9 = Concatenate()([u9, c9])
        c9 = conv2d_block(u9, num_filters=n_filters * 2)
        
        u10 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 1, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2),
                              padding='same')(c9)
        u10 = Concatenate()([u10, c1])
        u10 = Dropout(0.3)(u10)
        c10 = conv2d_block(u10, num_filters=n_filters * 1)
        
        outputs = Conv2D(2, (1, 1), activation='relu') (c10)
        model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
        return model
    

INPUT_SHAPE = (156, 156, 2)

model = build_unet(INPUT_SHAPE)
```

I have images with 2 channels.

At the first concatenation layer, `u6`, I am receiving:

```
 A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 8, 8, 256), (None, 4, 4, 512)]
```

If I change all `Conv2DTranspose` strides, with `strides=(1,1)` except the last `Conv2DTranspose` layer, and if I use `strides=(39, 39)` , then it works! But `39` strides?? Way too much.

```
...
        u6 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 16, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
                             padding='same')(c6)
        u6 = Concatenate()([u6, c6])
        c7 = conv2d_block(u6, num_filters=n_filters * 16)

        
        u7 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 8, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
                              padding='same')(c7)
        u7 = Concatenate()([u7, c7])
        c8 = conv2d_block(u7, num_filters=n_filters * 8)

        
        u8 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 4, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), 
                              padding='same')(c8)
        u8 = Concatenate()([u8, c8])
        c9 = conv2d_block(u8, num_filters=n_filters * 4)

         
        u9 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 2, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), 
                              padding='same')(c9)
        u9 = Concatenate()([u9, c9])
        c9 = conv2d_block(u9, num_filters=n_filters * 2)
        
        u10 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 1, (3, 3), strides=(39, 39),
                              padding='same')(c9)
        u10 = Concatenate()([u10, c1])
...
```

How to find the right dimensions?

Comment: You should definitely make sure that the number of filters for u6 (n_filters * 16) and c6 (n_filters * 32) match, which is currently not the case. You should look at the strides of both c6 and u6 and what they do to the size of the filter. I see you are currently using different strides for these layers. You can calculate the size of the filter for both convolution (height_filter= (current_height_filter - kernel) / stride + 1 (round down)) and deconvolution (height_filter =  (current_height_filter - 1) * stride + kernel) and calculate what you need to change to make them match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You concatenate the wrong layers. If you take a input shape of (256, 256, 3) for example, we can calculate the output shape of each block, given Conv2DTranspose with stride 2:

```
c1 -> (256, 256, 16)
p1 -> (128, 128, 16)

c2 -> (128, 128, 32)
p2 -> (64, 64, 32)

c3 -> (64, 64, 64)
p3 -> (32, 32, 64)

c4 -> (32, 32, 128)
p4 -> (16, 16, 128)

c5 -> (16, 16, 256)
p5 -> (8, 8, 256)

c6 -> (8, 8, 512) # this is the 'bottom' of your U-Net

u6 -> (16, 16, 256)
c7 -> (16, 16, 256)

u7 -> (32, 32, 128)
c8 -> (32, 32, 128)

u8 -> (64, 64, 64)
c9 -> (64, 64, 64)

u9 -> (128, 128, 32)
c9 -> (128, 128, 32)

u10 -> (256, 256, 16)
```

With this shapes, you can see that concatenating u6 and c6 doesn't work, and you should concatenate u6 and c5 instead.
After that, instead of concatenating u7 and c7, you should concatenate u7 and c4 and so on. When you take a look at the U-Net architecture in the original paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf) on page 2, you can see that the first layer is connected to the last, the second layer is connected to the second-to-last, and so on.
You can also get an overview of your model architecture with model.summary().

Comment: still can't get it right for (156,156,2)

Comment: What does model.summary() print? And which layers do you concatenate now?

Comment: I can't print model summary since I can't build the model. printing `c5,c6,u6` before first concatenation gives: `(shape=(None, 9, 9, 256)`, `(None, 4, 4, 512)`, `(None, 8, 8, 256)`.

Comment: Ah yes the problem is that you get rounding errors. `c5 -> (9x9)`, half of that is 4.5. The MaxPooling2D rounds it down to `c6 -> (4x4)`. If you upscale it again, you get double of (4x4), `u6 -> (8x8)`. (9x9) and (8x8) are not the same shape. Try to use multiples to the power of 2 (2,4,8,16,32,64..) as your image resolution to avoid getting uneven numbers when Pooling down, or count your pooling operations and see if your image resolution gets to decimal numbers when getting halved that many times.

Comment: Yeah , that;s the problem. I should use other dimensions. Thanks.